# Remove done button in M13PDFKit swift

Tags: swift, pdf, pdf-viewer, m13pdfkit

I'm using M13PDFKit and having a little problem. In the example the done button is not there, but when I try it shows. I don't know how to remove it. The done button looks like this. Im using Swift
[image]

in View controller just like this

```
import UIKit
import M13PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "NEXT" {
        let viewer: PDFKBasicPDFViewer = segue.destinationViewController as! PDFKBasicPDFViewer
        viewer.enableBookmarks = true
        viewer.enableBookmarks = true
        viewer.enableOpening = true
        viewer.enablePrinting = true
        viewer.enableSharing = true
        viewer.enableThumbnailSlider = true
        //Load the document (pdfUrl represents the path on the phone of the pdf document you wish to load)
        let pdfUrl = "/Users/developer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C8DC5F44-B2FC-4FC3-8E10-B87FC00791FA/data/Containers/Data/Application/047BE9AD-F43C-421E-B5B5-943B0C79B592/Documents/Yudi Seven.pdf"
        let document: PDFKDocument = PDFKDocument(contentsOfFile: pdfUrl, password: nil)
        viewer.loadDocument(document)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is that done button do have any action?

Comment: check edited question

Comment: i just download M13PDFKit from github. it seems like Done button appears in default?. let me see how to modify....

Comment: yep, it think the done button is default. I don't understand obj-c too much so i don't know what happen

Comment: i found the answer i will update the code in a min...

Comment: let me see... thanks

Comment: I got the answer. can you post another question and buzz me the link ...

Comment: let me know you posting another question? my time is limited...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380661/make-done-button-in-m13pdfkit-as-back-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto **PDFKBasicPDFViewer.m** disable the line(**line 247**) that highlighted in the first image and run the project....

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! But i want to ask you how to make the done button as back button? Or I should make another question?