# Make done button in M13PDFKit as Back Button

Tags: swift, pdf, m13pdfkit

I'm using M13PDFKit. The done button in this image, i want to make it as back button.
[image]

Comment: code uploaded......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto **PDFKBasicPDFViewer.m** and follow the steps.

**Step 1:**

[image]

Button code:

```
  self.backButtonTitle = @"Done";
  [buttonsArray addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.backButtonTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissed)]];
```

**Step 2:**

[image]

Dismiss View:

```
   - (void)dismissed
  {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]